# How to disable a radio button but not it's label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Okay so I am working on an html page with jquery mobile and I am disabling my radio buttons when the form they are on gets submitted but this causes the labels to get grayed out. I don't want the labels to be greyed out because I want to user to be able to see their previously entered choices. How can I disable the radio button but not disable/grey out the label when I disable the radio button?? Thanks for help in advance!

EDIT:

So to provide an example of what is happening go to this web page with radio buttons: 
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-radiobuttons.html

Then open up the console in the inspector and type these two lines:

```
$('input:radio').attr('disabled', true);
$('input:radio').checkboxradio("refresh");
```

The radio buttons will all be greyed out. I am trying to leave everything greyed out except for the labels.

Comment: Can you show us you here code here?

Comment: -snip-
I've tried it myself and disabling a radio button doesn't affect its text or label, it must be something in your CSS. http://jsfiddle.net/5x9CW/

Comment: Disabling a radio button shouldn't gray out a label next to it. If you can provide your code snippet, we can be more helpful.

Comment: Why would that grey out the label? Never seen that happen, and a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rpNyn/) tells me it doesn't ?

Comment: Okay sorry guys I seem to have forgotten to tell you that I am using jquery mobile to style my page. So it is possible that they radio button are getting greyed out by jquery mobile styling when I disable the set of radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using "disabled" semantics incorrectly. If they're disabled, they *have no previous value*, they have no value at all, and they will be absent from the form when submitted to the server.

If you want them to retain their value, don't disable them, make them read-only.

Comment: Well the disabling happens after the data has been sent to the server. I just want to disable them so that the user can see their past choices but not change them.

Comment: Then you *definitely* want read-only semantics, not disabled semantics. Disabled elements aren't supposed to have values.